# Upload data/nodes to Neo4j through python

Tags: python, neo4j

I have the following sentences; "Punta Cana is a resort town in the municipality of Higuey, in La Altagracia Province, the eastern most province of the Dominican Republic"

This sentence comes from the following page: https://huggingface.co/Babelscape/rebel-large

With the following code:

```
    from transformers import pipeline

    triplet_extractor = pipeline('text2text-generation', model='Babelscape/rebel-large', tokenizer='Babelscape/rebel-large')
    # We need to use the tokenizer manually since we need special tokens.
    extracted_text = triplet_extractor.tokenizer.batch_decode([triplet_extractor("Punta Cana is a resort town in the municipality of Higuey, in La Altagracia Province, the eastern most province of the Dominican Republic", return_tensors=True, return_text=False)[0]["generated_token_ids"]])
    print(extracted_text[0])
    # Function to parse the generated text and extract the triplets
    def extract_triplets(text):
        triplets = []
        relation, subject, relation, object_ = '', '', '', ''
        text = text.strip()
        current = 'x'
        for token in text.replace("<s>", "").replace("<pad>", "").replace("</s>", "").split():
            if token == "<triplet>":
                current = 't'
                if relation != '':
                    triplets.append({'head': subject.strip(), 'type': relation.strip(),'tail': object_.strip()})
                    relation = ''
                subject = ''
            elif token == "<subj>":
                current = 's'
                if relation != '':
                    triplets.append({'head': subject.strip(), 'type': relation.strip(),'tail': object_.strip()})
                object_ = ''
            elif token == "<obj>":
                current = 'o'
                relation = ''
            else:
                if current == 't':
                    subject += ' ' + token
                elif current == 's':
                    object_ += ' ' + token
                elif current == 'o':
                    relation += ' ' + token
        if subject != '' and relation != '' and object_ != '':
            triplets.append({'head': subject.strip(), 'type': relation.strip(),'tail': object_.strip()})
        return triplets
    extracted_triplets = extract_triplets(extracted_text[0])
extracted_triplets
```

This (should) produce the following output.

> <s>Punta Cana  La Altagracia Province  located in the administrative territorial entity  Dominican Republic  country  Higuey  La Altagracia Province  located in the administrative territorial entity  Dominican Republic  country  La Altagracia Province  Dominican Republic  country  Dominican Republic  La Altagracia Province  contains administrative territorial entity</s>
> [{'head': 'Punta Cana', 'type': 'located in the administrative territorial entity', 'tail': 'La Altagracia Province'}, {'head': 'Punta Cana', 'type': 'country', 'tail': 'Dominican Republic'}, {'head': 'Higuey', 'type': 'located in the administrative territorial entity', 'tail': 'La Altagracia Province'}, {'head': 'Higuey', 'type': 'country', 'tail': 'Dominican Republic'}, {'head': 'La Altagracia Province', 'type': 'country', 'tail': 'Dominican Republic'}, {'head': 'Dominican Republic', 'type': 'contains administrative territorial entity', 'tail': 'La Altagracia Province'}]

From this output I want to process the following part into neo4j via python.

```
[{'head': 'Punta Cana',
  'type': 'located in the administrative territorial entity',
  'tail': 'La Altagracia Province'},
 {'head': 'Punta Cana', 'type': 'country', 'tail': 'Dominican Republic'},
 {'head': 'Higuey',
  'type': 'located in the administrative territorial entity',
  'tail': 'La Altagracia Province'},
 {'head': 'Higuey', 'type': 'country', 'tail': 'Dominican Republic'},
 {'head': 'La Altagracia Province',
  'type': 'country',
  'tail': 'Dominican Republic'},
 {'head': 'Dominican Republic',
  'type': 'contains administrative territorial entity',
  'tail': 'La Altagracia Province'}]
```

Is there any way to do this efficiently?

Kind regards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use APOC for dynamic relationship types. Other than that, it should be pretty straighforward:

```
# Your output
data = [{head...}]

query = """
UNWIND $data AS row
MERGE (h:Entity {id: row.head})
MERGE (t:Entity {id: row.tail})
WITH row, h, t
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(h, toUpper(replace(row.type,' ', '_')),
  {},
  {},
  t,
  {}
)
YIELD rel
RETURN distinct 'done' AS result;
"""

with driver.session() as session:
    result = session.run(query, {'data':data})
```

Also make sure to create a unique constraint on Entity nodes for id property to optimize the import:

Comment: Thanks again! Difficult to understand the code in once, but seems to work in Neo4J! Did you copy paste this code from a certain page? If so, could you please share it? Thanks in advance : )

Comment: Yes, I copied from my post and changed it a bit. Take a look at https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.merge/apoc.merge.relationship/

Comment: I am sorry for commenting under this old threat, but do you know if it is possible to add a customized dataset to this REBEL module? If so, how?